# Opening Devtools on Chrome makes entire page trip

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a small website and I'm writing a website almost from scratch. I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I'm modifying only basic CSS.

Whenever I open the Chrome Devtools, the website completely flips out and it looks like it keeps reloading. The entire website only loads from localhost, however, the network tab keeps showing repeating requests to the saem assets, over and over again. The second I quit Devtools, the entire behavior stops. I've tried installing a cache killer, tried incognito, but the problems keeps appearing.

I'm also using Octicons, and what I have noticed is that when I manage to get the Devtools to at least stay focussed at the right part, the `<i class="oi oi-chevron-right">` node keeps flashing in purple, indicating there is a change to that node. I can't open it and even just clicking on it won't help, the entire CSS keeps shifting in the inspector bar and it seems like something is making rapid changes. It appears that Chrome re-applies styling changes that I made a few days back, such as locally modifying the margin of an element.

I was able to work on the website just fine a few days ago, but even moving back in commits won't keep the problem from happening. I am starting to think it is a bug with Chrome, but I can not confirm this in any way.

Is there anything that is known to break Chrome's Devtools, that might explain this behavior, or is there a way to clear the cache of the Chrome Devtools specifically?

The "Changes" tab in Devtools reports that there are no changes, but the CSS I see on page makes me seriously doubt it. Removing the icons entirely does not seem to resolve the problem, so I think the issue lies elsewhere. Breakpoints are not triggered either.

Comment: Can you try to open them is separate window? If it ain’t something on resize event?

Comment: @Akxe The Devtools is opened in a separate window, undocked, if that is what you mean? There's nothing on the resize event, at least, nothing configured by me. If this was a Bootstrap bug then I would've already found it I guess? To make matters worse, I can't reproduce it on my other PC. It only happens on my Mac.

Comment: Well... make a copy of the page, and trim something, try if it happens. If it does, trim again etc, once it stops, well share what it is that makes it go haywire.

Comment: This is happening to me on a 3rd party website.  Very annoying, and turning off all extensions does not seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

This could happen due to local overrides, check `dev tools -> network`, if there is a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark, hover over it and if the tooltip contains `Requests may be overridden locally...`, navigate to `sources`, click the `>>` button near `Page, Workspace` (or just make the left pane bigger), click `overrides` and uncheck `Enable local overrides`.

Comment: This appeared to solve the problem for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but,
Have you checked the chromium extension program?

Comment: What do you mean specifically? When I'm running in Incognito mode, none of the extensions are loaded because none of them have access, so that shouldn't be the issue. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The Chrome Devtools errors are almost caused by Extention or AntiVirus.
Even you turned on the Secret Mode, your extension can run (by options)
So you should check your all extension and antivirus